# Doctrine ClassTableInheritance Howto

Tags: doctrine-orm

i use two classes:

```
namespace Test;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 *@Table()
 *@InheritanceType("Joined")
 *@DiscriminatorMap({"baseclass"="BaseClass", "subclass"="SubClass"}
 *@Entity
*/
class BaseClass{

     /**
      *@Column(name="id", type="integer")
      *@Id
      *@GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
     private $id;
}


namespace Test;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 *@Table()
 *@Entity
 */
class SubClass extends BaseClass{

     /**
      * @Column(name="v", type="string", nullable="false")
      */
      private $v;
}
```

I am not able to persist a SubClassObject. I receive the following errorMessage:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'dtype' in 'field list'
```

I am new to Doctrine and ORM so I need some help here.

**Edit**: After using the cli orm:create-schema:tool the baseclass has a dtype-field. Is it possible to create the entity without that field and what does this field stand for?

Comment: Please note that issue
http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/DDC-2225/DDC-2225.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The dtype-field is the default [@DiscriminatorColumn](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/annotations-reference.html?highlight=annotations#annref-discriminatorcolumn). You can change the column name as follows:

```
@InheritanceType("Joined")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="[CHANGE]", type="string")
@DiscriminatorMap({"baseclass"="BaseClass", "subclass"="SubClass"}
```

In an [inheritance hierarchy](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/annotations-reference.html?highlight=annotations#inheritancetype) it is not possible to skip this field. This field maps the type to the appropriate class. In your example: Type subclass refers to the SubClass class.

Comment: Note that the links are broken. Can you update them please?